# Redirect user to fill attributes if null

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting to create a redirect feature as it stands right now my current function in my auth controller is if a film doesn't exist then it redirects to the page to create one. But I am wanting to change this now as this route is no longer needed. What I need instead is if a USER doesn't have an age or gender configured/set it redirects them to the user page `/user` with the new route name as `user_update`

Current function:

```
private function redirect(): RedirectResponse
{
    if (!$this->user->film()->exists()) {
        return redirect()->route('film_create');
    }
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

user model: the fields are set as constants with an array of values at the top of the model, e.g types of gender, age range

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'age',
    'gender',
];
```

do you know how i can modify the function above to create an IF statement to check if these fields are set for the user or not if not redirect them to the `/user` page?

having trouble trying to find resources on how to do this.

I am now writing a test for this function but having a little trouble on doing it..

this is the current test

```
  /**
 * @test
 * Create mocked user, send them to user page and assert they exists in database
 */
public function it_creates_user_on_redirect()
{
    $email = 'foo@bar.com';
    $this->mockSocialite($email);

    $this->get(route('auth_callback'))
        ->assertLocation(route('film_create'));

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
        'email' => $email,
    ]);
}
```

How do i go about modifying this test to ensure that it covers the new function ? @Saly 3301

Comment: why is the word `auth` in this question? I dont see how authenticating relates to a film that doesnt exist which should therefore redirect to `film_create`.

Comment: because i was working on a controller which handles auth, typo which i didn't adjust when i wrote out the question

Comment: Toxicity Overflow ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: honestly the elitism on this site sometimes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straightforward

```php
private function redirect(): RedirectResponse
{
    if ($this->user->age || $this->user->gender) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    return redirect()->route('user_update');
}
```

And here's the boolean logic in tinker

```
>>> NULL || NULL
=> false
>>> 25 || NULL
=> true
>>> NULL || 'female'
=> true
>>> 25 || 'female'
=> true
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem :)

Comment: yeah i tried to accept but i had to wait 2 minutes before i could :)

Comment: hey i've added a test above im having trouble trying to modify this to cover the new solution you've given above, can you give me a hand?

Comment: I'm sorry but you're not allowed to ask multiple questions on the same post, Ask a new question on a new post and we'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
private function redirect(): RedirectResponse{
    if (!($this->user->age &&  $this->user->gender)) {
      return redirect()->route('user_update');
    }
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Only if both fields are configured, you are redirected to 'home'

Comment: OP said "if a user doesn't have an age **OR** gender"

Comment: yes, if age is not set, redirect, or if gender is not set, redirect too...

Comment: But what if age is set and gender is not? this will still redirect

Comment: We clearly take the word OR differently. Your point is not bad.

Comment: it's not my point, it's [PHP's](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and every C like syntax language for that matter